# using sql statements to insert data from a textbox directly into a datatable

Tags: c#, sql, database, .net-3.5, datatable

**New Updates Below**

*My insert statement isn't executing when I run  insertSQL()*
I'm not sure if I am passing the parameters correctly. In my research, I see that SQL command is widely used to pass parameters, but this is the way that I am supposed to do it.

**This is my updated code:
FORM frmProcessLayout** -->

```
  public void insertSQL( string processName, string processingLevel, string department, string formName)
    {

        string[] parameters = new string[4];



        sSql = "INSERT INTO [ServiceStation].[dbo].[ProcessLayout] ([ProcessName], [ProcessingLevel], [Department], [FormName]) VALUES(@Parameter[0], @Parameter[1], @Parameter[2], @Parameter[3])";

        parameters[0] = processName;
        parameters[1] = processingLevel;
        parameters[2] = department;
        parameters[3] = formName;
        ssDBAccess.DBAccess oDb = new ssDBAccess.DBAccess();
        oDb.SetConnection();
        oDb.ExecuteNonSelectSQL(sSql, parameters);



    }
```

And this is what I'm looking at as reference to what I should do, but it is in Visual Basic

```
 Function addRow(ByVal fax As String, ByVal scan As String, ByVal backup As String)
        Dim parameters(2) As String
        Addrow = Nothing
        ssql = "INSERT INTO [ServiceStation].[dbo].[OnBaseSweepFaxPath] ([FaxLine],[FaxSweepPath] ,[FaxBackupPath])"
        ssql += "VALUES(@Parameter0, @Parameter1, @Parameter2)"
        parameters(0) = fax
        parameters(1) = scan
        parameters(2) = backup

        odb.ExecuteNonSelectSQL(ssql, parameters)
    End Function
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: John, do you have any suggestions on this question?

Comment: What is your exact problem? `dt == null` is not a problem in InsertSQL since its value is never used. If you have no other problems, then it's likely that you're just seeing an artifact of the debugger and code optimization. As far as `dt` is concerned, that code might as well be `DataTable dt = null;`.

Comment: After much fiddling, nothing gets inserted into the database, i'm not sure how to send the values to the parameter values

Comment: I suggest you create yourself a simple piece of code to reproduce this. It maybe should just be a Console application, to totally remove any complexity. Make it as simple as possible and see if you can insert data. If you can't, then post that code here. If you can, then start making the program more and more like the original, until it fails.

Comment: I was able to insert when I used a connection string with the username and pass, but since we already have a class that does that, i can't use the string i originally had. I was told to make a form that has a datagridview, and insert, update, and delete buttons. is it bad that I am having this much trouble/ this much time (7 days) to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's bad. It shows that you don't know how to break down your problem into its component parts (analysis). Really, try removing anything at all about forms, and just make the minimal program that should insert data into these tables.

Comment: Ok, I will try your suggestion. It's been awhile since I've coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two differences between your example code and your own `insertSQL()` implementation that might make a difference.

First, the example code calls a different method than your implementation of `insertSQL()`.  It calls `ExecuteNonSelectSQL()` and your code calls `ExecuteSelectSQL()`.  Just based on the name, I'd guess one is intended to return a result set and the other is not. I don't know if that would affect the execution of your `INSERT` statement, or not, but it might be worth investigating.

Second, the parameter names in the SQL statements are different. If your data-tier code is referring to parameters by name, it seems reasonable that it might also expect a certain naming convention for those parameters.

Your sample code uses the singular form of the word "parameter", e.g. `@Parameter0`, as below:

```
ssql = "INSERT INTO [ServiceStation].[dbo].[OnBaseSweepFaxPath] ([FaxLine],[FaxSweepPath] ,[FaxBackupPath])"
ssql += "VALUES(@Parameter0, @Parameter1, @Parameter2)"
```

While your code used the plural form of the word "parameter", e.g. `@parameters0` (note the extra 's') as below:

```
sSql = "INSERT INTO [ServiceStation].[dbo].[ProcessLayout] ([ProcessName], [ProcessingLevel], [Department], [FormName]) VALUES (@parameters0, @parameters1, @parameters2, @parameters3)";
```

If your data-tier is generating parameter names based on the number of elements in the `parameters` array, then if might include code like this:

```
string ParameterName;

for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
{
    ParameterName = "@Parameter" + i.ToString();
    //...
    command.Parameters[ParameterName].Value = parameters[0];
    //...
}
```

Which would fail because the SQL statement you passed to it says the name should be `@parameters0` instead of `@Parameter0` which is what it's trying to use.
See the sample code on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for more information on how the parameters named in the text of the SQL statement may be referred to in code.

Of course I have no idea if that's how your data-tier is implemented, but it's a difference that's easy enough to test.  Just change the text of your `VALUES` clause to match parameter names used in your example, like so:

```
sSql = "INSERT INTO [ServiceStation].[dbo].[ProcessLayout] ([ProcessName], [ProcessingLevel], [Department], [FormName]) VALUES (@Parameter0, @Parameter1, @Parameter2, @Parameter3)";
```

Comment: Matt, thank you for the response. I have updated my post to include what I have done this AM. One thing I did notice, like you've pointed out, is that I wasn't using a `ExecuteNonSelectSQL()` and I've changed my parameters to `@Parameter[0]` and so on... I've added an exception this is throwing when I step through some break points on oDb.ExecuteNonSelectSQL(sSql,parameters);

Comment: The image wasn't showing, so I added the code from DBAccess where the exception was thrown, and might give more insight into the parameters

Comment: It was definitely how I was naming the parameters in my Insert... I removed the brackets ie.. Parameter0,Parameter1,... and it works now.